# How to edit a function parameter within a function in C++

Tags: c++

How can I edit the values of a function's parameters so that they are modified outside the function. This is not from my code, this is just a very simple example:

```
bool func(int a, int b, int c, string word){
    a = a*a;
    b = b*b;
    c = a*b;
    word = "Score";
    return true;
}
```

So basically I need the function output to be a boolean, but I want my parameters to be edited in the function. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int &a, int &b, int &c, string &word
```

Comment: When I called the function in my main would it be: `func(x,y,z,str);` or `func(&x,&y,&z,&str)` or something else?

Comment: the former: func(x,y,z,str); The latter one won't compile, &x is a pointer, the address of x

Answer (score 2):

```
bool func(int& a, int& b, int& c, string& word){
    a = a*a;
    b = b*b;
    c = a*b;
    word = "Score";
    return true;
}
```

The caller:

```
int aVal = 2;
int bVal = 3;
int cVal = -1;
string wordVal;
func(aVal, bVal, cVal, wordVal);
//aVal == 4
//bVal == 9
//cVal == 36
//wordVal == "Score"
```